# How to pass Multiple Variables as Arguments to a Script using Start-job

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How to pass Multiple Variables as Arguments to a Script using Start-job.

```
  Start-Job -Name "$jobName" -filepath $TestTool -ArgumentList $compare1
```

how to retrieve this argument values (of $arg1 and $arg2) in a script TestTool.ps1?

Rgds
Naveen

Comment: your question is not very clear

Answer (score 11):

```
 PS>Start-Job -Name test -ArgumentList @("hello","word") -FilePath \\server\share\test.ps1
```

in test.ps1 just echo the $args var

```
   $args
```

result :

```
PS>Receive-Job test -keep
hello
word
```

Answer (score 3):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849698.aspx

"Because all of the values that follow the ArgumentList parameter name are interpreted as being values of ArgumentList, the ArgumentList parameter should be the last parameter in the command."

So I guess tha something like:

```
... -ArgumentList $arg1 $arg2
```

should work?

Comment: how to retrieve this argument values (of $arg1 and $arg2) in a script TestTool.ps1?

Comment: Number of arguments - `$args.lenghth`. First argument: `$args[0]`, second: `$args[1]`, etc.